# Отправка альбома в telegram канал. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить отправку нескольких фотографий в telegram канал, так, чтобы они отображались одним постом (альбом), а не каждая фотография отдельным постом.
Отправляю, используя [python telegram bot api](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot).
Код:

```
import telebot
for j in range(c):
        bot.send_photo(channel_name, post_media[j]['photo']['src_xxbig'])
```

Answer (score 2):

В API это реализовано методом [sendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup):

> Use this method to send a group of photos or videos as an album. On
>   success, an array of the sent ***Messages*** is returned.
>
> - ***chat_id***  - Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the    target channel (in the format @*channelusername*)
> - ***media***    - A JSON-serialized array describing    photos and videos to be sent, must include 2–10 items
> - ***disable_notification*** - Sends the messages silently.    Users will receive a notification with no sound
> - ***reply_to_message_id*** - If the messages are a reply, ID    of the original message

В библиотеке *python telegram bot api* это реализовано одноимённым методом [sendMediaGroup](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=sendmediagroup#telegram.Bot.sendMediaGroup).

Comment: При реализации этого метода, мне вываливается bad request: 
"The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body: Bad Request: there is no messages to send".
Вот реализация:
    photos = []
    for j in range(c):
    photos.insert(j, post_media[j]['photo']['src_xxbig'])
    bot.send_media_group(channel_name, photos)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('files/1.jpg', 'rb') as f1, open('files/2.jpg', 'rb') as f2:
            bot.send_media_group(call.message.chat.id, [InputMediaPhoto(f1), InputMediaPhoto(f2)])
```

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup

`media` - Массив `InputMediaAudio`, `InputMediaDocument`, `InputMediaPhoto` и `InputMediaVideo`.

[документация pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/554b39a49aceccac02a7759affe897a43737255b/telebot/__init__.py#L1282)

Сериализованный в формате JSON массив, описывающий отправляемые сообщения, должен включать от 2 до 10 элементов.

Comment: в ответ внесена правка

Answer (score 0):

У telebot для python можно сделать так:

```html
from telebot.types import InputMediaPhoto
def send_album_with_text(message):
        wget.download("https://example.com/766793/15675732133090s.jpg")
        pic1 = open("15675732133090s.jpg", "rb")
        wget.download("https://example.com/766793/15675732133111s.jpg")
        pic2 = open("15675732133111s.jpg", "rb")
        media = [InputMediaPhoto(pic1, caption="test"), InputMediaPhoto(pic2)]
        bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media)
```